# External HDD is causing second drive to unallocate (disappear)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid, bsod

I am running Windows 7 x64 and have two drives, C and D. D is within a RAID array running under Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST). The external HDD in question is a [CN Memory Spaceloop 2TB 3.5'' USB 3.0](http://www.amazon.de/CN-Memory-Spaceloop-externe-Festplatte/dp/B0047Q6G8I), and was newly bought.

**The problem:** I start copying files from D to this HDD as to back them up and leave the PC at it. After a while, Windows is logged out and after logging in, my D drive is missing. Disk management says Disk 1 is unallocated. On another attempt, instead of logging out from Windows, I got a BSOD. After rebooting and starting Windows, my D drive was gone.

**Because D is part of a RAID array, I can rebuild this volume via IRST and everything goes back to normal.** However, it is the second Spaceloop HDD I am trying out, so it certainly is not the external HDD. Some people had mentioned that I might have bad sectors on my D drive, yet software such as HDD Guardian 0.6.2 stated otherwise.

So, is my D drive failing? If I must replace it, how can I undertake a backup if every time I try copying files off of it, it crashes my Windows?

Comment: I had a problem years ago similar. It ended up being a bad connection and had to be replaced (replaced the cable).

Comment: Another thing comes to mind. In the old days, D was always D for "Disk Tray", where the DVD or Disk ROM. Is letter D drive a good idea? Sound like you installed this yourself. Just like A is for Diskette. Although these things are "old", hardware tends to be "old-ly" written. Also, BIOS comes to mind.

Comment: @ejbytes Hey thank you. so you replaced the SATA cable? I could try changing the drive's name and see if that does something.

Comment: Yes, and yes. See if that helps. Also edited my comment above.

Comment: Thanks - what about BIOS comes to mind?