# RAID-1 fails when moving files out of disk

Tags: windows-7, backup, raid-1

I am using Windows 7 x64, and have an SSD as my OS drive (C:) and a RAID-1 on (D:). **I want to backup my files in D:, so I am trying to copy-paste its files onto another drive.** *Initially*, [I wanted to move them to an external HDD.](https://superuser.com/questions/1088001/external-hdd-is-causing-second-drive-to-unallocate-disappear) While doing this, after a while, Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST) displays a flag, saying one of the disks has failed. As can be read in the link above, if the copy-pasting continues, my RAID fails and after Windows reboots, D: is gone. *Now* I have connected an internal HDD via SATA to my PC, and attempted the same: copy-paste the files from D: into my new HDD (E:). Unsurprisingly, Intel RST displayed an error once again.

In short, **moving files out of my D: drive seems to "break" my RAID-1 setup** (or it seems to alter Intel RST somehow). How can I backup these files ASAP?

Comment: Has the Intel RST identified which disk has failed? You should remove (or disconnect) said disk... This will put the array into a degraded state but, because it's RAID1, the data is identical on both disks so the working disk should continue to work as normal.

Comment: @BigChris Hey, thank you for your time! The one at Controller 1, Phy 2 fails. Is that the answer you needed?

Comment: I don't need an answer.. you do lol! I'm suggesting for you to remove the failed disk and see if you can get your data off the remaining, working disk ;)

Comment: @BigChris You mean physically disconnecting the disk, correct? Not deleting the RAID volume.

Comment: Physically disconnect the disk only.

Comment: @BigChris Once disconnected, should I change the SATA mode in BIOS to IDE or AHCI instead of RAID, or keep it at RAID for now? Thank you, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Leave the settings exactly as they are. RAID looks after itself so don't worry

Comment: @BigChris Alright, thanks. I disconnected the disk, rebooted Windows and am trying the backup again.